# SQL insert avoid column names

Tags: sql, hibernate, insert

In SQL insert, generally we specify the names of the columns in the SQL. Is there a way to generate that dynamically? basically if we specify the names of columns then tomorrow if a new col is added, there is a code change involved. How can i avoid this?

I am thinking of follg solution -

How about getting the names of the columns via 
select column_name,* from information_schema.columns where table_name = '' order by ordinal_position;
& then create the INSERT statement with the columns? This way we do not specify the column names in the SQL...
Any thoughts?

Comment: How could you **not** change the code if more columns are in the table. Where do you get the values for the new columns without coding?

Comment: it is possible to do all SQL generation dynamically.  probably not what you really want however.

Comment: How can I make a code change without making a code change?  Its too early in the morning for questions like this.

Comment: Concerning your edit: and what do you want to put into those columns?

Comment: What does this have to do with Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by getting the names of the columns via 
select column_name,* from information_schema.columns where table_name = '' order by ordinal_position;
& then create the INSERT statement with the columns. By this I avoided specifying the column names in the query

Answer (score 1):

You can only leave out the column names if you fill all values, but that would also break if a new column is added.

If you specify the names, you can add new columns as much as you want. They will automatically be assigned their default value if you leave your query as it is.

If you don't want them to have the default value, you need to edit the code anyway. Sure, you can dynamically generate the SQL and assign a default value, but that is what your RDBMS does anyway! I don't see your problem.

Comment: thats true Cularis. However i am trying to avoid a code change here. Hence thinking of some alternative

Comment: And how do you know WHAT to put into those new columns you dynamically inserted into your queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a default value for the new column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're saying that you'll be getting the column values as input from somewhere else, then you could keep the column names in a config file like a properties file. Then if you're willing to assume that the ordering will always match up, just match up the input values to the column names from the file, and adding a column just means getting a new value to match the new column.